# Prestashop 1.6: how to load a different template after an admin form submission?

Tags: prestashop

I'm new to Prestashop and currently working on a custom admin module in 1.6.

My scenario is, users can load orders to this module/admin controller and from the list they can select which ever order they like using 'Select All' checkbox selector.

And then these selected order ids are submitted back to admin controller to be displayed on a different template with full information in a form.
And then again this form will be submitted to a third party API for further processing.

Now my problem is I can get the order listing to my admin controller and get them submitted back to the same controller. But I do not know how to switch to a different template to display in a form.

And also how to call a different method to process and export once second form substitution is done.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Roshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AdminController extend the method initContent with a condition that is you need to check if a certain button was pressed. Something like

```
public function initContent()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('the_button')) {
        'do what you want to do'
    }
    parent::initContent();
}
```

if you want to redirect to a different controller use Tools::redirectAdmin() and set the path of redirection like Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink('your_another_controller', true), also you can send all necessary data with the third parameter of the method(array)

```
public function initContent()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('the_button')) {
        Tools::redirectAdmin(
            Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink('your_another_controller', true, $orders)
        );
    }
    parent::initContent();
}
```

You can use as many conditions, inside the method, as you need so I hope it will help you in all your cases.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander, This is what exactly I was looking for. Much appreciated!